# Is there a way to add a global directive for NS elements?

Tags: nativescript

NativeScript provides a method to add custom properties to a component of your choice as mentioned here: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/properties.
Is there any way to add a custom property to all existing components? Just like Angular ng directives.

I'm using NS with plain JS.

EDITED: Added working code sample.

app.js

```
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");
const Property = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties").Property;
const View = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view").View;

const hiddenProperty = new Property(
{
    name: "hidden",
    defaultValue: false,
    affectsLayout: true,
    valueChanged: (target, oldValue, newValue) => 
    {
        console.log("New value is: " + newValue);
    },
});
hiddenProperty.register(View);

application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });

/*
Do not place any code after the application has been started as it will not
be executed on iOS.
*/
```

Comment: Yes, of course. You can update the prototype chain of `View` or `ViewBase` which is inherited by all nativescript components.

Comment: This worked pretty well, thanks! I added a code sample at first post in case it's useful for people.